# What are my kitchen sink's drain pipes made of, and how should I seal connections?

Tags: plumbing, kitchens, drain, sink

I'm going to attempt to replace my sink drain pipes (highlighted in red below) in addition to replacing my sink basket.

I have a question about the pipes: can someone confirm the material of these pipes? I would like to buy replacement pipes of the same material.

Also, for the connections between each elbow, is teflon tape needed? Or can I just tighten the connections with the slip nut?

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: I would use the teflon and not just tighten. It is cheap and it works better than a putty and definitely will work better than nothing. Not sure why you want the metal pipes but to each his own. PVC works just as well but is cheaper.

Answer (score 2):

Those are brass drain pipes, which were once quite popular but now are more expensive than plastic. Most brass drain & faucet assembies are chrome plated.

There should be rubber or plastic seals, not Teflon tape to create the seal (although I have seen Teflon cord wrapped around the pipe to make a seal), but this is not as good as it flows out of the nut.

Comment: If brass drain pipes aren't available, is there another material you would recommend for my setup?

Comment: "Tubular" is the magic word for threaded together assemblies like you have. Your local plumbing supply (as opposed to home center) should have both brass and tubular pvc. Though in replacing what you've drawn I'd consider matching the chrome plated trap.

Comment: I agree with Mathew most plumbing or big box stores will have both plastic or metal, just don't use the flexstuff that looks like an accordion that stuff catches soap scum and hair faster and if bumped tends to spring leaks more easily.

Comment: I was able to replace the entire assembly using brass piping from Home Depot. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like copper drain pipe. http://www.freeonlineplumber.com/copdrain.html